# How would caching with this GET request work?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, caching

I recently heard that my GET requests would be cached and im having questions about what that would mean to my case.

I send a GET request using javascript:

```
var ajax = new XMLHtpprequest();
ajax.open("GET", "https://my-website.com/somepage.php");
ajax.onload = function () {
    // do something depending on the echoed response
}
ajax.send();
```

And in my somepage.php :

```
$wp_user_id = get_current_user_id();
// echo something depending on the $wp_user_id back
```

My understanding is that when different logged in users open the ajax-call they get the last cached ajax call, which could be incoherent with their individual wp_user_id.

I use wordpress without plugins on my webserver.

My questions:

- Am i right with this or have i understand something wrong about caching?
- If im wrong whats the best way to stop this behaviour?

Thanks for any answers in advance!

Comment: To properly assess the cacheability of that URL you need to provide request and response headers (you can get them from browser dev tools).

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/response

you just need to write a response handler. (and listen for onreadystatechange)

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
    responseHandlerCallback(xhr.response);
  }
}
```

to prevent caching of requests, use a cachebuster

```
https://yourdomain.com/web-api/handler.php?cb=ej0d293dj
```